# Access issue in Azure data lake

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

We are moving files from SFTP to Azure data lake using Azure data factory (V2). We have already created a static folder structure inside the lake and the current user has all the permission inside the folder. But when we move the files from the Source (SFTP) to the folder current user don't have any access for file but the folder permission are look like same as before the transformation

[File Permission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdMTI.png)

[Folder Permission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ox7Xm.png)

[Access Control exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYQoF.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by insufficient permissions, you can give it read, write, and execute permissions.

[image]